# How to flip an image vertically using ImageSharp/C#

Tags: c#, imagesharp

Because Y-axis is inverted I would like to flip my resulting image vertically.
[image: vertical_flip]

Currently this is how my code looks like:

```
using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (Image img = new Image<Rgba32>(width, height))
  {
     PathBuilder pb = drawPath(); // draw Path draws everything

     IPath path = pb.Build();
     path.AsClosedPath();

     img.Mutate(imageContext => imageContext
       .BackgroundColor(Color.Black)
       .Fill(Color.Yellow, path)
     );

     img.SaveAsPng(outStream);
  }
  
  return File(outStream.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

I have not yet understod how the FlipExtensions and FlipMode works in ImageSharp, maybe it's not even possible to use it to flip my image.

How am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (Image img = new Image<Rgba32>(width, height))
  {
     PathBuilder pb = drawPath(); // draw Path draws everything

     IPath path = pb.Build();
     path.AsClosedPath();

     img.Mutate(imageContext => imageContext
       .BackgroundColor(Color.Black)
       .Fill(Color.Yellow, path)
     );

     img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

     img.SaveAsPng(outStream);
  }
  
  return File(outStream.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.